# Difficulty with the usage of Cauchy's integral formula in Griffiths QM book

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, calculus

On page 410 of Griffiths QM 2nd Ed. book, he begins an analysis to evaluate the integral:
$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s \sin{(sr)}}{(s-k)(s+k)}\mathrm{d}s.$$
To exploit Cauchy's formula, he dissolves the integral into:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s e^{isr}}{(s-k)(s+k)}\mathrm{d}s-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s e^{-isr}}{(s-k)(s+k)}\mathrm{d}s.$$

Now he chooses a contour by which he overlooks the poles (at $\pm k$). The poles are (at least apparently) the most severe points. Is this a rigorous analysis? After all, for each of these two integrals I can choose a contour containing no poles at all, and hence each is zero. That is not the answer.
I looked for mathematical sources that discusses this particular point, and I found none.

Comment: Have you ever taken a course on complex analysis? I suggest you read up a little on that topic; this seems to be a standard application.

Comment: That's the fundamental problem actually: I haven't!

Comment: Then read up on it. An elementary approach is outlined in e.g. Kreyszig's book 'Advanced Engineering Mathematics'

Comment: Look for "Residue theorem" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem , there are plenty of lectures on it available on youtube as well.

Comment: @Phonon The reason why your link doesn't resolve the issue is  that, in my case, the poles are right in the original real integral interval

Comment: The reason why I'm questioning the rigor is that the real integral can have no more than one value, while different choices of the contours yield different answers.

Comment: I assure you, contour integration is perfectly rigorous (although I didnt inspect your specific case).

Comment: I assure you, too, that I'm by NO means questioning the rigor of contour integration, but the way it's applied to my specific case.

Comment: The usual trick is to shift the poles off the real axis then take the limit of the pole moving back onto the axis. If you do the contour integration correctly, the answer is unique.

Comment: The point is that if you choose a contour to not include the poles in the "half semi circle way" then the real integral isn't actually equal to the complex integral. The two integrals being equal hinges on the fact that the half-semi circle needs to be zero. This is known as Jordan's lemma.

Comment: Hi kalkanistovinko. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 6):

The integral $$I(k) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s e^{isr}}{(s-k)(s+k)} ds \tag{1}$$
where $k$ is real and the integration is for real $s$, is not really well-defined. This is precisely because the integrand has singularities on the integration domain. However consider if $k$ is a *complex* number $k = k_r + ik_i$ with $k_i >0$. Then the integrand is smooth on the whole integration domain. We can even calculate the integral using the residue theorem. It turns out that $$ I(k) = i\pi e^{ikr}.$$

As it stands $I(k)$ is only defined for complex numbers with non-zero imaginary part, but since the expression for $I(k)$ certainly makes sense for all complex numbers, we can extend it to the case where $k$ is real. If you draw the poles of the integrand in (1) you see that integration along the real axis is below one pole and above the other. Since the complex integral depends only on the winding numbers about each pole, when taking $k_i \to 0$ you can think of it as the contour having to bend to keep the poles on the same side; this gives the contour in Griffiths's Figure 11.9.

Taking instead $k_i < 0$ will give another contour, but as explained in Griffiths's book for the present purpose this is immaterial.